# Authentication login problem in running two django projects at the same time in same PC machine

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-settings, django-sessions

I have two different django projects in same a computer and i run both the project by giving command `python manage.py runserver 8000` and `python manage.py runserver 8001`. They both run without any error but when i open them in a same chrome browser in two different tabs and trying to login in both projects they are reset and return to login page again.

I am trying to say that when i login in first project it login successfully and then i login in second project it also login successfully but the first project comes to reset and return in login page again. it seems that browser only allows only one login at a time.

is there anything about django session either in Cookies session or Authentication Session?
and do i have to add or change something in settings.py file?

Answer (score 0):

What you should know is that when you login, the session cookie is stored in browser which is then sent in every request to the server. The cookie is set for a domain on which you are logging in which in your case is localhost.
So because in both of your application the domain name is same "localhost" and hence the cookie is getting overridden by the next project you start.
To resolve this you can either run one your project on 127.0.0.1:8000 and the other one on localhost:8001.
This way the cookie wont get overridden because the domain names are different now.
You can also use your systems ip instead of localhost to run one of your project.

You can view what cookie is being set and on what domain by visiting inspect section on chrome and then navigating to application section there -> cookies -> yourdomain

Comment: Thank you so much for such a immediate and well explained Answer. This solved the problem. thank you